# Converting Rules to a row matrix

Tags: matrix, rule

How can I convert a list of rules

`{a -> 1, b-> 2, c-> 3, d-> 4}`

to a row matrix by removing the keys like

`{1, 2, 3, 4`}.

thanks

Comment: [`Values@rules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Values.html?q=Values)

Comment: Last/@ {a -> 1, b-> 2, c-> 3, d-> 4}

Answer (score 7):

If you define `rule = {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4}`, then there are at least four ways that can reach what you want:

```
rule[[All, 2]]
Thread[rule, Rule][[2]]
Cases[rule, _?NumericQ, 2]
rule /. Rule[_Symbol, a_Integer] :> a
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.